# How to select columns based on row values?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following tibble:

```
## # A tibble: 16 x 4
##    name              genus        order        sleep_total
##    <chr>             <chr>        <chr>              <dbl>
##  1 Cheetah           Acinonyx     Carnivora          12.1 
##  2 Northern fur seal Callorhinus  Carnivora           8.70
##  3 Vesper mouse      Calomys      Rodentia            7.00
##  4 Dog               Canis        Carnivora          10.1 
##  5 Roe deer          Capreolus    Artiodactyla        3.00
##  6 Goat              Capri        Artiodactyla        5.30
##  7 Guinea pig        Cavis        Rodentia            9.40
##  8 Domestic cat      Felis        Carnivora          12.5 
##  9 Gray seal         Haliochoerus Carnivora           6.20
## 10 Tiger             Panthera     Carnivora          15.8 
## 11 Jaguar            Panthera     Carnivora          10.4 
## 12 Lion              Panthera     Carnivora          13.5 
## 13 Caspian seal      Phoca        Carnivora           3.50
## 14 Genet             Genetta      Carnivora           6.30
## 15 Arctic fox        Vulpes       Carnivora          12.5 
## 16 Red fox           Vulpes       Carnivora           9.80
```

I'd like to only select the columns that contain at least one row value called 'Carnivora'.

The expected output in this case would be:

```
## order       
## <chr>       
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Rodentia    
## Carnivora   
## Artiodactyla
## Artiodactyla
## Rodentia    
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora   
## Carnivora
```

Someone else has provided how to get the *rows* that contain this. However, this includes columns that don't contain this value.

```
sleep %>% 
  select(name:order, sleep_total, -vore) %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = "Ca")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot2::msleep %>% select_if(~any(. == "Carnivora", na.rm = TRUE))

#          order
#1     Carnivora
#2     Carnivora
#3      Rodentia
#4     Carnivora
#5  Artiodactyla
#6  Artiodactyla
#7      Rodentia
#8     Carnivora
#9     Carnivora
#10    Carnivora
#11    Carnivora
#12    Carnivora
#13    Carnivora
#14    Carnivora
#15    Carnivora
#16    Carnivora
```

Or in base R using `colSums`

```
msleep[colSums(msleep == "Carnivora", na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
```

Or `apply`

```
msleep[apply(msleep == "Carnivora", 2, any, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

Comment: `<error>
message: Only strings can be converted to symbols
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. dplyr::select_if(., ~any(. == "Carnivora"))
  9. dplyr:::vars_select_syms(vars, funs, .tbl)
 10. rlang::syms(vars)
 11. rlang:::map(x, sym)
 12. base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 13. rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 14. dplyr::select_if(., ~any(. == "Carnivora"))`

@RonakShah

Comment: @PDog seems to work fine for me. Can you share the `dput` of your tibble? `dput(sleep)` ?

Comment: Too many character for the full output, but here's where the dataframe is from.

sleep <- ggplot2::msleep
dput(sleep)

`structure(list(name = c("Cheetah", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-83L))`

Comment: @PDog ohh..I see..there are `NA` characters in it hence the error. We need to do add `na.rm = TRUE`. Updated the answer.

Comment: 100% on me, my apologies. I was also able to extend this for partial string matching!

`sleep %>%
  select_if(~any(str_detect(., "Ca"), na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` in base R with `sapply`

```
library(ggplot2)
msleep[sapply(msleep, function(x) "Carnivora" %in% x)]
```